# Python how to force method to take only instacne of the class as a parameter

Tags: python, methods, annotations

How can I specify that only instance of this class can be given as a parameter to this class methods? When I tried to use annotations it says class name is not defined.
For example I have class Atom and I want methods get_distance_to and get_energy_with to only take instances of class Atom itself as the second parameter:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from random import uniform
from math import dist


@ dataclass
class Atom():

    A: int = 0.5  # ???? Как конкретно работают эти коэфиценты 
    B: int = 0.5
    position: list = field(default_factory=list)
    

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if not self.position:
            self.position = [uniform(0, 10),
                      uniform(0, 10),
                      uniform(0, 10)]  # x y z

    def get_distance_to(self, atom):
        return dist(self.position,
                    atom.position)

    def get_energy_with(self, atom):
        A_general = self.A + atom.A
        B_general = self.B + atom.B
        r = self.get_distance_to(atom)

        U = (A_general / (r**12)) - (B_general / (r**6))
        
        return U
```

Comment: annotate with `: "Atom"` ...using quoted string gets around fact that class def is not fully executed when the annotation is encountered

Comment: @Anentropic  but it is just a string, not the class itself

Comment: yes but mypy understands that as meaning the class name

Comment: in Python 3.11 it will be possible to use a new `Self` type https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/